# extract specific data from array in mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

This is the data that i need to extract like example profile_contact_numbers
so the output will be +639466276715

how can i do it in php code??
any help will do regards
a:2:

```
{s:23:"profile_contact_numbers";s:13:"+639466276715";s:16:"profile_position";s:7:"Courier";}
```

Comment: What have you done so far? share some code.

Comment: It looks like data serialized with `serialize()`, but it's not: https://3v4l.org/fJ6Pu

Comment: the example you give the using serialize is working but the problem in the sample is you forget to put a:2:

Comment: I think you are getting String type.. please cast to date type in json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure 100% this can go into an array but try the unserialize function

```
$json_resp = {your values};
$array[] = unserialize($json_resp);
```

To check if it has gone into an array `print_r` on `$array`.

Read this link if the code above doesn't work

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

I have managed to fix it

```
$serialized = array(unserialize('a:2:{s:23:"profile_contact_numbers";s:13:"+639466276715";s:16:"profile_position";s:7:"Courier";}'));
var_dump($serialized);
```

Comment: i already tried the above code and its not showing any data any clue why?? dont have any idea how to do it

Comment: I have managed to get the serialized data to output into an array but it is only show 1 value 
https://3v4l.org/IlVCH

Comment: @driandrian I have found out the issue

Comment: i found the issue the " a:2:" i forgot to add in the beginning of the serialize data

Comment: @driandrian don't forget to mark this as an answer so you don't keep getting notifications haha

Answer (score 0):

use code :

```
$var = preg_split('["]','{s:23:"profile_contact_numbers";s:13:"+639466276715";s:16:"profile_position";s:7:"Courier";}');
echo $var[1].'='.$var[3]; // profile_contact_numbers=+639466276715
echo $var[5].'='.$var[7]; // profile_position=Courier
```